# Ionic 2 background of pop up is still clickable

Tags: ionic2

when i show an alert on the page, user is be able to click the background and alert dismisses. Is there any way to make the background not clickable ?

```
this.alert = this.alertController.create({
                                title: 'Error',
                                subTitle: "You lost connection !",
                                buttons: [ {
                                text: 'Refresh',
                                handler: () => {
                                    if(!data){
                                    this.alert.dismiss().then(() => {
                                        this.alert = null;
                                 });
                                    }
                        }
                    }]
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the enableBackdropDismiss option to false while creating the alert. For eg:

```
this.alert = this.alertController.create({
                                title: 'Error',
                                subTitle: "You lost connection !",
                                enableBackdropDismiss: false,
                                buttons: [ {
                                text: 'Refresh',
                                handler: () => {
                                    if(!data){
                                    this.alert.dismiss().then(() => {
                                        this.alert = null;
                                 });
                                    }
                        }
                    }]
                });
```

Hope this helped you. Thanks.